# MariaDB case sensitive Unicode collation

Tags: mariadb

I see no `%_cs` Unicode collations in MariaDB (10.3.21, Debian). But I do need to have case sensitive primary key column where `'a' != 'A'` (I'm migrating tables from MySQL). Is it not supported in MariaDB? How can I achieve my needs?

Comment: It's spelled `_cs`.  Let's see the `SHOW COLLATION` that is disturbing you.

Comment: It was my typo in the question